# ThunderBolt 3 to Firewire 800?

Tags: thunderbolt, firewire

I have several FireWire 800 Hard disks full of data/video/images I need for work. Last week I bought a brand new iMac and only today I realized that Apple is not selling any Thunderbolt 3 to FW800 adapter?

I couldn't believe it, and I hope there is a solution otherwise I will switch away from Apple forever.

Comment: It seems like a bit of a stretch of dump Apple because they no longer support a long since obsoleted technology (Firewire).    This is like getting angry with them because [Apple Desktop Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Desktop_Bus) is also, no longer supported.

Comment: You are a victim of Technology evolution. .....Designer Apple Inc. ...
...Designed 1986; 32 years ago
...Produced 1994–2013
**Superseded by Thunderbolt and USB 3.0**

Comment: Amazon has Apple Thunderbolt to FireWire Adapter for $30. its here:  https://www.amazon.com/Apple-Thunderbolt-to-Firewire-Adapter/dp/B00SQ2CJUS/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=firewire+800+to+Thunderbolt&qid=1555527935&s=gateway&sr=8-3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buy a drive caddy for $22.00 (USB3).
Take all your old Firewire drives apart pull each disk out, and slip them into your modern caddy. Plug the caddy into USB and pull your data off as needed.

Don't toss the drives. You can use them for backup media etc. through the caddy.
Be sure you do a modern reformat on the drives, and run Disk First Aid.

Comment: I've got 3 of the Sabrent caddies around. They are darn useful.

Comment: This way the speed of the disk is reduced to the USB3 speed...

Comment: @FabioMarzocca - Firewire 800 is 800Mb/s while USB 3 is 5Gb/s; in other words, USB 3 is 6x *faster* than Firewire.

Comment: @Allan, you're right. My bad...

Answer (score 5):

After a quick search I found out there is a solution:

Have an Apple Thunderbolt 3 to Apple Thunderbolt 2 cable

Then you can have an Apple Thunderbolt 2 to Firewire 800 cable

I do not think there is a way to connect it directly.

Comment: Yes, I knew that "solution", but I wouldn't define exactly as a solution. Does a 2,000 $ computer need such a patched cable to work with FW800 disks (which is an Apple protocol!)? 
I feel cheated by Apple.

Comment: @FabioMarzocca Yeah I agree. I do not like what Apple has done

Comment: [FireWire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1394) was made obsolete by Thunderbolt 1 and USB 3.0. which is now almost a decade since inception.  The market is *very small* for Thunderbolt 3 to Firewire adapters  and makes no sense to continue the development.

Comment: Thunderbolt ports are stupidly scarce resources on most Macs. Include the option for Docks with FW (although even more expensive) and I'll +1. ("Superseded" 'obsolete' are spits in my face as well…, but hey, this is the Appleverse.)

Comment: Does it matter if you need to put two adapters together to get what you want?  Both adapters are made by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different -- but the title makes this question comes up in Google for audio gear as well: if you have Firewire gear you can't convert and want to connect, OWC has a Thunderbolt 3 dock with a Firewire port. Noone else has such, AFAIK. https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/docks/owc-thunderbolt-3-dock/firewire

Comment: OWC has now discontinued the Thunderbolt 3 dock with the firewire port.

Comment: Would like to add to the OWC dock comment that it was a great dock for professional audio, where there are still many FW interfaces and converters (as opposed to storage) still the primary hardware in studios. However I am currently with one that just died after about 6 months of use, and am unable to replace with anything similar. Although it remains the only TB3 to FW dock one might run into on craigslist or the back shelf of a big box store, sadly I don't recommend it.

Comment: Apparently still available at Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/OWC-Port-Thunderbolt-Dock-Space/dp/B01N51P3BB/

Answer (score 1):

Just take the drives out of their enclosures. They're going to be standard SATA Drives on the inside. You can then just put it into a Thunderbolt or USB 2/3/C enclosure (~$25 online).

Oops, didn't see @Wayfaring-Stranger's post. Yes. That.

Comment: How is this any different from what the accepted and highest voted answer already says? If you wish to agree, please up vote and/or leave a comment.